# Why would you start multiple thin servers?

Tags: thin

In the Thin website: http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/usage/ it says that you can start multiple servers using:

```
thin start --servers 3
```

1. Why would you need to do this?
2. Is each server assigned a different port or something?

Answer (score 7):

1. You would start more than one instante of **thin** if you may have **concurrent requests to process**. To manage concurrent requests (Simultaneous connections)  you need **a cluster of "thin"**.
2. Yes, 
   you can easily see this:

let's try a single-server thin

```
 thin start -R fart.ru
 Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
 Maximum connections set to 1024
 Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

check:

```
 netstat -an | grep 300
 tcp4       0      0  *.3000                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

ok, we have a thin listening on one port.

now let's try a --servers 3

```
 thin start -R fart.ru --servers 3
 Starting server on 0.0.0.0:3000 ... 
 Starting server on 0.0.0.0:3001 ... 
 Starting server on 0.0.0.0:3002 ...
```

check:

```
 netstat -an | grep 300
 tcp4       0      0  *.3002                 *.*                    LISTEN     
 tcp4       0      0  *.3001                 *.*                    LISTEN     
 tcp4       0      0  *.3000                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

voilà you have 3 port listening.

```
 ps -ef | grep thin
```

reports 3 processes running, each one can manage a concurrent request.

Ultimately to concurrently process requests you have to start a cluster of thin and reverse proxy your virtual host then load balance the request on the various thin you've started.

This blogpost can make the point: [Scaling Rails with Apache 2, mod_proxy_balancer and Thin Clusters](http://jpaulh.blogspot.it/2008/03/scaling-rails-with-apache-2.html)

Comment: For how many requests per second do you need more thin servers?

Comment: quoting http://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/9/9/ruby-the-bad-parts/ The performance of multithreaded applications is still limited, though. Ruby interpreter uses mechanism called GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) which allows only one thread to execute at a time, even if ran on multi-processor system i.e. if you have quad core system may be resources are better utilized. Anyway load and performance testing is recommended and useful to understand how this can or not apply to your application and runtime environment.

Comment: This information about the GIL is wrong. The `--servers` parameters will start up several ruby processes, *not* threads. This is an important distinction, because the GIL can only affect threads within the same process, not separate processes. By that chain of logic, you wouldn't be able to run completely different ruby programs on the same machine, because their GIL's would affect each other.